# AlphaAnimation without fading in/out

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

Can I ask if is it possible to create an alpha animation without the fading in/out?
So ultimately, it will be on and off only.

Snippet of my code so far:

```
imPreview.setImageDrawable(imgColorDotPreview);
Animation animationFlashing = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
animationFlashing.setDuration(5000);
animationFlashing.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation infinitely
animationFlashing.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
imPreview.setAnimation(animationFlashing);
startAnimation();
```

I was thinking for another way, which is without using AlphaAnimation, that is just directly set the image's alpha to 0 and 1 with a timer. But then I need to make it infinitely.

Any help and suggestion is very much appreciated! Thanks guys!

Comment: If I understood right, you just need to set the visibility of the imageview to Gone/Visible then you don't need to change the alpha at all!!

Comment: @SaeidFarivar but then how to make it visible and invisible every 0.5 second? and it needs to be continuously visible and invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally solved it my own with someworkaround using the AlphaAnimation.

I used setOnAnimationListener and change the Alpha of the image in the onRepeat().

```
imPreview.setImageDrawable(imgColorDotPreviewFlashing);
final Animation animationFlashing = new AlphaAnimation(1f,1f);
animationFlashing.setDuration(250); // duration - quarter a second
animationFlashing.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation infinitely
animationFlashing.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
animationFlashing.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if(animation == animationFlashing){
        imPreview.setImageAlpha(255);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        if(animation == animationFlashing){
            if(imPreview.getImageAlpha()==0) imPreview.setImageAlpha(255);
            else imPreview.setImageAlpha(0);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        if(animation == animationFlashing){
            imPreview.setImageAlpha(255);
        }
    }
});                          
imPreview.setAnimation(animationFlashing);
startAnimation();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just set the view visibility:

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: but then how to make it visible and invisible every 0.5 second? and it needs to be continuously visible and invisible.

Comment: You can not sleep the main thread, as that will cause an ANR. You will need to run a timer task or another thread that will update the UI thread when needed.

Comment: that's why i tried using alphaanimation to get the on/off effect. but it uses fading in/out in between. guess there's no way to get it done with alphaanimation then?

Comment: I think your best bet would be using `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(), 0, 500);` This will run a task (toggle the visibility) every so specified often.

Comment: thanks for your sugesstion Matt! I tried it and work though my implementation was buggy since I need to restart the timer often. Maybe my implementation was wrong... But anyway, I solved it with a workaround! :) Thanks!